# Ckeditor - why dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules does not work? How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I want to make that when creating a paragraph in the ckeditor, a certain class is automatically added to it. I wrote this code, but it does not work.

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {
        var editor = ev.editor;
        editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules({
            elements: {
                p: function (el) {
                    el.addClass('myClass');
                }
            }
        });
});
```

Why? How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Please use something like below. You should use `dataFilter` instead of `htmlFilter` and the best approach would be using both of them in order to avoid cases where you create paragraph with no class in design/wysiwyg mode and then you switch to source mode or get data from the editor.

```
        var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
            language: 'en',
            extraPlugins : 'placeholder',
            on: {
                pluginsLoaded: function( evt ) {
                    evt.editor.dataProcessor.dataFilter.addRules( {
                        elements: {
                            p: function( el ) {
                                //The Html filter works when you load data into editor.
                                if(!el.hasClass('nomargins'))
                                    el.addClass('nomargins');
                            }
                        }
                    } );
                    evt.editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules( {
                        elements: {
                            p: function( el ) {
                                //The Html filter works when you get data from editor.
                                if(!el.hasClass('nomargins'))
                                    el.addClass('nomargins');
                            }
                        }
                    } );
                }
            }
        });
```